# GitlabHQ - W denied for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, gitlab

At work I've been tasked with setting up out GIT server with a front end and I found GitlabHQ which looks amazing.

I've installed it all semi-successfully but I cannot push my repos at all as it says I need to push them.

Since I've never used GitLabHQ before first is:

```
You should push repository to proceed.
After push you will be able to browse code, commits etc.
```

Normal when adding projects?

and every-time I run

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get this,

```
W access for focus DENIED to rails
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

is anyone able to help since I can't expect the team to keep SSH'ing?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Server = Ubuntu Server 11.10 fully updated and I followed these instructions: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/V2.0-easy-setup-for-ubuntu

Comment: Sounds like you may be trying to push to a non existant repository.  Did you create a repository to push to?  It's also possible you may not have added the repository as a remote to your project?  You also must add it as a remote to your project using `git remote add origin git://repo_location.git`.  [Read this for more info on how to use the git remote command.](http://help.github.com/remotes/)

Comment: It keeps telling me remote origin already exists?

Comment: What happens when you execute `git remote show origin`?

Comment: It just gives me the original error "R access for focus DENIED to rails"

Comment: Sorry mate, I've never used that system.  I'm as lost as you are.  Maybe you need to change the access permissions for the user that the server is being run under or something so it can actually read/write to the directories where the repo's are?  You may want to take a look at [github](http://www.github.com/).  It's nice and simple, and truly a pleasure to use.

Comment: Hrmm, that's a bummer out internet blows hence opting for the local choice! Anyways, thanks for your help buddy!

Comment: I think you have a problem with your ssh_keys, have you uploaded your key through gitlab gui ?

Comment: I actually managed to fix it, I re-ran the gitolite install which seemed to fix it. I also added the ssh key to the known_hosts file and all seems to work. Gitolite seems flaky though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by re-running the install (It must have failed silently the first time) and killing the process once it had started with

```
lsof -p :3000
kill 9 {Whatever the PID was returned from above}
```

Then re-running the bundle (differs between production or not) I use this

```
bundle exec rails s -e production -d
```